# Plot a curve, show on the axis only a specific symbolic value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'd like to plot a curve like the following (TTR=1-e^{-t}; t*=-log(0.2); TTR_PLATEAU=1):

[image]

So far I know only how show a series of symbolic values on axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$TTR$},
        axis lines=center,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
        xmin=0,xmax=4.9,
        ymin=0,ymax=4.9,
        xticklabel={$t_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$},
        yticklabel={$TTR_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$}
]

\addplot +[mark=none,smooth] {1-e^(-x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xtick`/`ytick` is used to set ticks at specific locations, `xticklabels`/`yticklabels` (note `s` at the end) is used to provide a list of labels (rather than providing a pattern, as one does with `xticklabel`).

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% also loads graphicx
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$TTR$},
        axis lines=center,
        xmin=0,xmax=4.9,
        ymin=0,ymax=4.9,
        ytick={0.8,1},
        xtick={1.61},
        xticklabels={$t^*$},
        yticklabels={80\% TTR\_PL, TTR\_PLATEAU}
]

\addplot +[mark=none,smooth] {1-e^(-x)};
\draw [dashed] (0,0.8) -| (1.61,0);
\draw [dashed] (0,1) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},1);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing, short, extremely clear, code! @Torbjørn T.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the y axis length? For example length(y axis)=length(x axis)/2.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi See chapter 4.10 *Scaling options* in the `pgfplots` manual. There are `width` and `height` keys that you can use to set the size of the axis, add e.g. `width=8cm,height=4cm` to the `axis` options. By default the lengths you define include some space for labels, so the actual size of the axis box is a little bit smaller. If you add `scale only axis` to the `axis` options, `width` and `height` apply to the axis box only, so the total size (including axis labels/ticklabels) will be larger.

Comment: Thank you @Torbjørn T. I was wrong because my last question is not pertinent with the initial question.

Answer (score 8):

alternatively, by use of `intersections` library:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$TTR$},
        axis lines=center,
        ymin=0, ymax=2,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        no marks,
        every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
        clip=false
]

\addplot +[name path=A,domain=0:5] {1-e^(-x)};
\path [name path=B] (0,0.8) -- + (5,0);
\draw [name intersections={of=A and B, by={a}}, dashed]
    (0,0.8) node[left] {\SI{80}{\%}TTR\_PL}  -| (a |- 0,0) node[below] {$t*$};
\draw[dashed] (0,1)node[left] {TTR\_PLATEAU} -- + (5,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I put parameter `no marks` inside `axis` definition but it printed the marks anyway (see my answer). How can I get rid of them.

Comment: @Cragfelt, hm, my image is drawn by code in answer. i check it again and it works as intended. last test with two small changes in code (curve is now in blue and thick) are put in answer. so you should have in your tests something different from code in answer. the same axis options  i also use in the answer on your next question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404465/.

Comment: @Zarko I have achieved plotting the axis with no ticks. I've just put  `xtick=\empty` and `ytick=\empty`. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: this you can see in my answer ...

Comment: @Zarko and there is where I took it from. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Too late

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel={$TTR$},
    axis lines=center,
    xtick={\empty},
    ytick={\empty},
    xmin=0,xmax=4.9,
    ymin=0,ymax=4.9,
    extra x ticks={1.6,0},
    extra y ticks={0.75,1.2},
    extra x tick labels={$t^*$},
    extra y tick labels={$80\%$~TTR\_PL, TTR\_PLATEAU},
    no marks,
]
\addplot +[mark=none,smooth,ultra thick] {1-e^(-x)};
\addplot[thick,dashed,domain=0:5] {1};
\addplot[thick,dashed] coordinates {(1.6,0) (1.6,0.7981)};
\addplot[thick,dashed] coordinates {(0,0.7981) (1.6,0.7981)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution @Cragfelt.

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this with MetaPost and its `intersectionpoint` operator, for whom it may interest. Integrated in a LuaLaTeX program via the `luamplib` package.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
    \mplibnumbersystem{double}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    u = cm; v = 2cm; xmax = 4.9; ymax = 1.9; xstep = .1; 
    beginfig(1);
        % graph and intersection
        path graph; 
        graph = origin for t = xstep step xstep until xmax: .. (t, 1-exp(-t)) endfor;
        draw graph xyscaled (u, v) withcolor red;
        z = ((0, .8) -- (infinity, .8)) intersectionpoint graph;
        draw ((x, 0) -- z -- (0, y)) xyscaled (u, v) dashed evenly;
        draw (0, v) -- (xmax*u, v) dashed evenly;
        % Axes and labels
        drawarrow origin -- (xmax*u, 0);
        label.bot("$t^*$", (x*u, 0));
        label.bot("$t$", (xmax*u, 0));
        drawarrow origin -- (0, ymax*v);
        label.lft("\textsc{TTR\_PLATEAU}", (0, v));
        label.lft("\textsc{80~\%~TTR\_PL}", (0, .8v));
        label.lft("\textsc{TTR}", (0, ymax*v));
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]