# Plot two curves on the same figure, axis without ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I tried to plot two curves on the same figure, but without ticks on axis. Latex gave me an error "Dimension too large" (it allows me to plot only a single curve). What can I do to remedy the situation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$TTR$},
        axis lines=center,
        xmin=0,xmax=4.9,
        ymin=0,ymax=2,
        ytick={0},
        xtick={0}
]

\addplot +[mark=none,smooth] {1-e^(-x)};
\addplot +[mark=none,smooth] {e^(-x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

you should define function domain. as basis for above image i use [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404447/plot-a-curve-show-on-the-axis-only-a-specific-symbolic-value/404453#404453) on your previous question:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$t$},
        ylabel={$TTR$},
        axis lines=center,
        ymin=0, ymax=2,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        no marks,
        domain=0:5
]

\addplot {1-e^(-x)};
\addplot {e^(-x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! Very good @Zarko!